# Does paypal changes the order of POST fields in every IPN notification?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I read that I need to send a confirmation to paypal with the fields in the same order plus the *cmd=_notify-validate* field. I know that for certains event the fields will be different, but for example for a notification of paid using paypal buttons, will the params will always be in the same order?

Due some limitations I can't get the whole POST fields array (I can only get them by explicitely calling the key) so an option is to set each field in the confirmation request to paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it's always the same order is irrelevant. You're supposed to send them back in the same order they arrived in, whatever that was.

BUT I don't believe that observing the same order in the validation request is necessary, and in some languages, e.g. Java, it isn't even possible, as the order isn't preserved. I've been running IPN for several years without observing this constraint, and I've only ever had one validation failure, from Turkey, which remains unexplained but could have been say a character set issue.

Note that PayPal provide sample code for Java somewhere which therefore doesn't observe the constraint either. One assumes it was tested and passed a review ...